# Having trouble displaying images in one row/two rows using media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, display

I want have a responsive page whereby if the screen is large enough, my login images are displayed on one line, otherwise, they are displayed across two lines.  So I have this HTML

```
<div id="loginBox">
    <div>Login/Sign Up</div>
    <div id="loginLogos">
            <div id="row1">
        <a href="/auth/google"><img border="0" alt="Google" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/google_plus_icon-8d7622763257233cf58e0465806f58d7c4b82b85271c2d03d0e02b2fadc4ac76.jpg"></a>
                <a href="/auth/facebook"><img border="0" alt="Facebook" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/facebook-b74d7c49fd91aa6ca76518bf46c7b75fa3b23f47028bea4b2ffaa39f5776dd91.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="row2">
                <a href="/auth/twitter"><img border="0" alt="Twitter" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/twitter_icon-7dbf8db24c3ad328ea28cba340e4f53e033b64b149850324822cdb622d77f331.png"></a>
        <a href="/auth/linkedin"><img border="0" alt="LinkedIn" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/linkedin-1d4c0d36adcec44fd86c11c47834e51e3f3226b623f91a2f215993633956e431.png"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then I used the media-query to attempt to do what I wanted …

```
#one {
    float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   #one {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

However, at a normal screen size, the images are falling into two rows instead of one — https://jsfiddle.net/ocdz4bsp/ .  For small screens, they are correctly wrapping into two rows.  How do I keep everything on one line for screen sizes over 400 pixels?

Comment: If you just put `float: left;` on both `row1` and `row2`, they will stay side-by-side until they can no longer fit, at which point the second one will drop beneath the first - no media queries necessary. Also, please review your code... both your fiddle and CSS reference an ID of "one", which doesn't exist anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need any media queries to achieve the effect you're after. By using floats properly, the items will stack themselves when need be. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ocdz4bsp/3/)

```
#row1, #row2 {
    float:left;
}

#row1 {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

If you were set on `@media` queries, then you could do the following:

```
#row1, #row2 {
    float:left;
}

#row1 {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #row1, #row2 {
        float: none;
        margin-right: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 elements to be side by side, use `display: inline-block`  If you want them to stack on top of each other use `display: block`

Here is the corrected fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ocdz4bsp/1/

Hope this helps.